# How to Integrate $1/\left(x\sqrt{1-4x^2}\right)$?

Tags: functions, inverse, substitution

How do I integrate:

$$\frac 1t\sqrt{1-4x^2}$$

I am thinking about (Integrals of Inverse Hyperbolic Function):

$$\frac{-1}{a} \operatorname{arcsech}\left(\frac xa\right)+C$$

But do I need to use substitution for $2x$?

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{x}$ or $\frac{1}{t}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\right)\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\sqrt{1-4x^2}$ and $\text{d}u=-\frac{4x}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\left(\frac{1}{u^2-1}\right)\text{d}u=$$
$$-\int\left(\frac{1}{1-u^2}\right)\text{d}u=$$
$$-\tanh^{-1}(u)+C$$

Substitute everything back and you got the final answer!

Comment: Thanks for the hint!  I got it!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

let $2x=\sin \theta\implies 2dx=\cos\theta d\theta$ $$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\ dx$$ $$=\frac{2}{2}\int \frac{\cos\theta\ d\theta}{\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}$$
$$=\int \frac{\cos\theta\ d\theta}{\sin\theta|\cos\theta|}$$

Comment: use the trigonometric identities with this type of infinite integral is not suitable because there is the absolute in the integral. But use the hyperbolic functions will not need the absolute because the function always positive

Comment: for example $|\cos\theta|\neq \cos\theta$ but $|\cosh\theta|= \cosh\theta$